# PHP MySQL if date and time unavailable add to alert message

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and a new student and so I will ask in advance to please forgive me if I have made errors that will be clearly obvious to someone experienced.

I am working on a page submission form that connects to a mysql database to either check for an existing value and if it does not exist then logs a string value of the datetime picker and also appends an id number to make a unique value to a table whenever someone was to press submit, and after form validation is accepted.  Submitting if the record does not exist works and is ok.

However, whenever a record already exists, rather than displaying in the error message that the time is unavailable, the entire page just goes blank.

Initially, I had a button that would check to see if the record existed in the mysql table but I then decided it would be more efficient to try to include the date validation check of mysql table while completing the form validation and this is where I have trouble and of course the page breaks and nothing is displayed.

If someone could please guide me I would be most grateful.

it seems I am unable to add more code, but I will add what was wrong.

I did need to initialize `$error='';` also `$DateTime`, and `$id` at the top of the script, I had it below but had forgotten to place it above and that was causing my problem.

```
    <?php

    $userid = "1";
    $strid = strval($id);
    $DateTimeCheck = $DateTime . $strid;
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
    $con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT booked FROM user_booking WHERE `booked` = :booked";
    $sqlprep = $con->prepare($sql);
    $ar_val = array(':booked' => $DateTimeCheck);

    if (isset($_POST['datetime'])){

        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $error = "<br/>- Please enter your name";
        }
        if (!$_POST['email']) {
            $error .= "<br/>- Please enter your email";
        }
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $error .= "<br/>- Please enter a message";
        }
        if (!$_POST['check']) {
            $error .= "<br/>- Please confirm you are human";
        }
        if ($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {
        while ($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $DateTimeExists = $row->booked;
        }
    }
    if (isset($DateTimeExists) && $DateTimeExists != ''){
        $error .= "<br/>- The time you have requested is unavailable";
    }

    if ($error) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Whoops, there is an error</strong>. Please correct the following: ' . $error . '</div>';
        } else {
            mail("@gmail.com", "Contact message", "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "
        Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "
        When: " . $_POST['datetime'] . "
        Message: " . $_POST['message']);
            {
                $result = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you, someone will be in touch soon to confirm your appointment. </div>';

                $id = "$userid";
                $strid = strval($id);
                $DateTime = $_POST['datetime'];
                $DateTimeCheck = $DateTime . $strid;
                $strid = strval($id);
                $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
                $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user_booking ( user_id, booked ) VALUES ( :id, :booked )";
                $q = $con->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array(':booked' => $DateTime . $strid,
                    ':id' => $id));
                $con = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

?>

Here is the markup for the form.

```
                <form method="post" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name"
                               value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email"
                               value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" align="left">
                        <label class="control-label">Date/Time</label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' name="datetime" class="form-control" placeholder="desired time"
                                   value="<?php echo $_POST['datetime']; ?>">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control"
                                      placeholder="message..."><?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox" align="left">
                        <label class="readable" align="left">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check"> I am human
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div align="left">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Book Appointment!"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: _Small Point_ Query 1. If it returns only one row, you dont need the loop `while ($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {`. If it returns more than one row, you will loose all but the last reference to `$row->booked` because you are assigning it to a scalar variable

Comment: How do you get error response from php ? `$error .= "<br/>- Please confirm you are human";`

Comment: Hello @Dilek, I am using checkbox for validating the "I am human".

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, I will update that.  I do only need one row.

Comment: Maybe some tips:
 - $error is maybe undefined and will trow an error/ blank page
 - Check if email address is valid so the mail function will not crash
 - Check if the date is valid and what if I take a time 1 minute after the one is taken?
 - Sanitize all your variables for save output in the email or html page
 - Your check function for human will not work, maybe you can better add an input field with name="firstname" and hide it with css, a bot will fill this in but a human wont because he cant see it. on server side check if post firstname is empty

Comment: Try using php's error reporting.

Comment: @SteveInCA beter you put all your code in `if (isset($_POST['datetime'])){` exept `error = '';` so your code would not run aparts.

Comment: @Dilek You dont need to `@address` the user on their own question. The Asker always gets notified of any comments

Comment: @Baracuda078 thank you!!  that $error not being initialized was absolutely causing me issues, you helped resolve this for me, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.=` you need to first initialise the variable before `.=` will work on the variable.

You attempted to do that in this IF block

```
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $error = "<br/>- Please enter your name";
}
```

but if that error is not present you will never actually initialise the `$error` variable.

So the simple solution is to initialise `$error` before getting into this section of code

```
$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['datetime'])){

    // So now you can change this test to use .=
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $error .= "<br/>- Please enter your name";
    }
```

Now the variable will be testable later in the code

> If this is in fact the problem here, you should have been getting errors reported. If you didnt see any then try adding these lines of code to any problem script while you test it

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: I am not sure, can you check his first query on top if need and execute.

Comment: I have added this and initialized the variable, thank you.

Comment: @SteveInCA Change this `$ar_val = array(':booked' => $DateTimeCheck);` to `$ar_val = $sqlprep->execute(array(':booked' => $DateTimeCheck));` because you are using pdo

Comment: he is pdo @RiggsFolly tought it wont give the result if no execute not right ?

Comment: @Dilek No dont do that

Comment: @Dilek He executes the query further down the script in this line `if ($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for the error checking!  I want to upvote but I am new and stack won't show it, this is great.

Comment: You will get the option to accept the answer after a period of time 20 minutes or so I think

Comment: Ok, so the error checking saved my LIFE!  thank you guys you are all fantastic, so now it does work, you were all correct and led me to the answer, I had variables not being initialized and it was throwing the error.  Once I initialized the page is working.  I will post an edit of the revised code.

Comment: Steve, dont amend the Question. You can however post an answer if you think it will be better for those that come and find this question than mine

Comment: @RiggsFolly hello, your answer was very helpful, and it was a combination of each person who provided feedback that led me to my answer, what I did was write the items that I corrected, I have left the original code as it was posted, thanks again.